# Unable to fetch record using wildcard search using Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch the value from mongoDB using like query but no record is fetching as many record matches with input text. My query is below:

```
if (req.body.searchText != '' && req.body.searchText != null) {
        products = await productsCollection.find({ Name : /req.body.searchText/});
        console.log('input products', products);
}
```

I am trying to perform the any where search (`'%m%'`) but as the records are there I am getting the blank value in console. I need the input text will match anywhere of the `Name` value and records will be fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with defining regex:

```
if (req.body.searchText != '' && req.body.searchText != null) {
        products = await productsCollection.find({ Name : { $regex: req.body.searchText, $options: 'i' } });
        console.log('input products', products);
}
```

or:

```
if (req.body.searchText != '' && req.body.searchText != null) {
            products = await productsCollection.find({ Name : new RegExp(req.body.searchText) } });
            console.log('input products', products);
    }
```